# Ruby - find keywords despite case-sensitive

Tags: ruby, case-sensitive

```
u = gets.chomp
if u.include? "tree"
  # ...
```

in this code ruby will search for `tree` word, but it will ignore all other cases
like `Tree` or `tReE` etc

is there a way to tell ruby that i don't care about case
and catch all the words despite their cases?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have (at least) two solutions to this problem :

- downcase u and compare with 'tree' `u.downcase.include? 'tree'`
- use case-insensitive regex `u.match(/tree/i)`

Bonus specs :

- Is 'treetop' supposed to match ?

If not, use the regex `/\btree\b/i` or scan your sentence for the word tree like so:

```
u.downcase.scan(/\w+/).include?('tree')
```

Comment: than you soo much bro

Comment: @A7lamLover If this works you should accept this answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could downcase first:

```
u.downcase.include?("tree")
```

EDIT following comments:

could include downcase for general search terms

```
u.downcase.include?(x.downcase)
```

Comment: `"tree".downcase` doesn't do much ;-)

Comment: true, I was thinking more for general search terms see edit

Comment: @Dawcars : `"tree".include?("TRe".downcase)` not worked as OP's requirement, still it returns `true`

Comment: It should return true. The OP wants to match against all cases

Comment: @Dawcars : `tree` and `Tre` both are not same strings even case-insensitively

Answer (score 1):

A simpler solution involving just a regex match:

```
u = gets.chomp

if u =~ /tree/i
  # ...
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Check [**String#casecmp**](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-casecmp). It returns `0` if two strings are **equal**, case-insensitively.

```
> string1.casecmp(string2) == 0
#=> true 

> "tree".casecmp("TRee") == 0
#=> true
> "tree".casecmp("TrEe") == 0
#=> true
> "tree".casecmp("trEE") == 0
#=> true
> "tree".casecmp("trEEe") == 0
#=> false
```

Try:

```
u = gets.chomp
if u.casecmp("tree") == 0
```

**Note:** `downcase` not works for everycase, see below example

```
> "tree".include?("TRe".downcase)
#=> true
```